# Why isn't the surface area of a shell in a sphere the difference between two spherical caps?

Tags: geometry, area

In geometry, a spherical cap or spherical dome is a portion of a sphere or of a ball cut off by a plane. It is also a spherical segment of one base, i.e., bounded by a single plane. [(Wikipedia)][1]

[In a proof of the Shell Theorem, it is stated that the area of a thin ring of shell of a sphere is 2πR2sin(θ)dθ][2]

The thing is, I can actually understand the derivation of this formula but even so, I'm stuck on why it can not be the difference of caps, as:

$2πRh_1 - 2πRh_2$

Is this something similar to the volume of a cone not being $πr²h$?
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9LMs.png

Answer (score 1):

Let us use $z$ instead of $h$. Assume $0\le z_1< z_2 \le R$, then notice that
\begin{align}
\text{area of the ring}=-2\pi R(z_2-z_1) = -2\pi R\Delta z.
\end{align}
Infinitesimally, we have that
\begin{align}
\text{area of the ''thin" ring}=-2\pi R\ dz.
\end{align}
Since $z = R\cos\phi$, then we have that
\begin{align}
dz = \frac{dz}{dR} dR+\frac{dz}{d\phi} d\phi = -R\sin\phi d\phi
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\text{area of the ''thin" ring}=2\pi R^2\sin\phi d\phi.
\end{align}